# Magento contact form unable to submit your request error

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, contact-form

Magento 1.9.2.3 contact form issue, its the default contact form in magento. I get error `Unable to submit your request, please try again later`, even all fields are filled, however this form is submitted and we get email but error still appears for users using that form.

I have narrowed down this error to:

```
 if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 throw new Exception();
 }
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`

when I comment out the code above, it will give correct message ("Success, your query has been sent...").

What's the fix for this? Is above code necessary? I will get the please fill all fields error if I leave some of the required field blank.

Answer (score 0):

Cade,your issue may be in

- Mail Configuration at server.Mail need to  be setup properly at magento
  system & your server.
- If Mail setup is  proper then you need to check `contact_form.html`
  exits in *app/locale/en_US/template/email*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @Amit Bera says that there is a problem with the email template or the send mail configuration. check if you changed the email template, and check if you have some extension like Mandrill or SMTP pro extension. That coul have bad configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you removed some field from the form `form.phtml` but you always have the check validation in controller if that field is `not empty`, and since this field is not filled so you get the error, please check all fields from the **form** and their validation in a **controller**.